# CastError: Cast to number failed for value "xxx" at path "yyy" for model "qqq" Mongoose & Express

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I am building app using express and mongoose, and I keep getting this error:
CastError: Cast to number failed for value "Security" at path "age" for model "persons"

mongoose model

```
   const PersonSchema = new Schema({
     skills: [String],
     age: Number
   });

   const Person = mongoose.model("persons", PersonSchema);
```

express router

```
app.get("/api/person/skill/:skill",(req, res, next)=>{

const humanSkill = req.params.skill;

    Person.find({ humanSkill: { $in: skill } })
      .then(humans => {
        res.send(humans);
      })
      .catch(next);
});
```

And this is url that I call (Security is some example skill)

```
http://localhost:3050/api/person/skill/Security
```

I suspect error is caused by  `skills: [String]` , but I dont know how to fix it, any help?
Thx in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
app.get("/api/person/skill/:skill",(req, res, next)=>{

const paramSkill = req.params.skill;

//DatabaseSkillKey is the database object key which is defined in Schema
Person.find({ DatabaseSkillKey: { $in: paramSkill } })
  .then(humans => {
    res.send(humans);
  })
  .catch(next);
```

});

Comment: And how to access that DatabaseSkillKey ?

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:

I menaged to solve the problem by changing the url path.
Now it is:

```
app.get("/findbyskill/person/skill/:skills", ()=>{});
```

It is not a perfect solution, as I was really eager to get to the bottom of this thing, but it worked...
Hope this will help someone